# SQL Server stored procedure concat string as query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, stored-procedures

I wonder if can I define some parts of the my sql query as a string.

I worked on the code below but I could not manage to concat that pre-defined string part to the existing query.

Actually `@sirketid`, `@uzman`, `@basvurukodu` params works well, however the `@ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL` param is causing a problem.

I think because it has some sql-spesific expression like ***and***, it is treated diffrently than simple variables used for comparison or assigning such as `@sirket_id`.

It does not throw any error message, the code simply does not excute the operation.

```
SET @ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL = 'and akftif = 1';

UPDATE basvuru 
SET sirket = @sirketid,
    talep_gorevlendirme_rapor = 'G',
    birimi = 'SS', 
    uzman = @uzman,
WHERE
    kod = @basvurukodu + ' ' + @ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL;
```

Can I concat query parts like this, if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: you will need dynamic sql. first concatenate the whole SQL you want to execute and finally execute the SQL with EXEC

Comment: You cannot concat e new condition on like that. To do that you have to make the query dynamic

Comment: [Background material for your perusal](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), and also [this](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) more in general for dynamic SQL. There's a lot to say about this topic. Passing in arbitrary SQL as a parameter is almost never a good approach, due to the risk of injection involved.

Comment: This is really complicated than I thoght :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should work like:

1. Concatenate the whole Query
2. Execute the query with `EXEC`

of course you have to declare the other variables too:

```
SET @ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL = 'and akftif = 1';

DECLARE @MyExecSQL varchar(2000) =
    'UPDATE basvuru 
        SET sirket = @sirketid
           ,talep_gorevlendirme_rapor = ''G''
           ,birimi = ''SS''
           ,uzman = ' + @uzman + 
     ' WHERE kod = ' + @basvurukodu + 
        ' ' + @ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL + ''
;     
EXEC @MyExecSQL
```

Comment: Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, there's no reason to settle for anything less. `@sirketid` will be undefined. Concatenating string parameters this way won't work, they'll need to be escaped. Using `EXEC` rather than `sp_executesql` with parameters may cause a lot of query plan cache pollution. With dynamic SQL, the devil's in the details.

Comment: I had to use `EXEC (@MyExecSQL)`